# PushViewController doesn't work after httpPost

Tags: ios, swift3

I have made a login screen which takes the input and communicates with the REST api to verify the user. If the response is true, I login the user else not.
I have written a method openViewControllerBasedOnIdentifier(id) to switch views.

The REST api returns true and false appropriately. The push controller gets called but view does not change. How if I place only one line in LoginAction method 'self.openViewControllerBasedOnIdentifier("PlayVC")' and remove the rest of the code , it works fine.

Here is my code
        @IBAction func LoginAction(_ sender: Any) {

```
    //self.openViewControllerBasedOnIdentifier("PlayVC")

Constants.login_status = false
    //created NSURL
    let requestURL = NSURL(string: URL_BK)

    //creating NSMutableURLRequest
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: requestURL! as URL)

    //setting the method to post
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let username = phonenumber.text

    //creating the post parameter by concatenating the keys and values from text field
    let postParameters = "username="+username!+"&password=bk&schoolId=0";

    //adding the parameters to request body
    request.httpBody = postParameters.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)


    //creating a task to send the post request
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){
        data, response, error in
        let responseData = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        if error != nil{
            print("error is \(error)")
            return;
        }

        //parsing the response
        do {

            print(“Received data is ---%@",responseData as Any)

            let myJSON =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data! , options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary


            if let parseJSON = myJSON {


                var status : Bool!

                status = parseJSON["status"] as! Bool?
                //print(status)

                if status==false
                {
                    Constants.login_status = false

                                        }
                else{
                    Constants.login_status = true
                    print("calling PLAYVC")

                    self.openViewControllerBasedOnIdentifier("PlayVC")


                }

            }
            else{
                print("NULL VALUE RECEIVED")
            }


        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

    }
    //executing the task
    task.resume()




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should open the new view controller on the main thread like this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.openViewControllerBasedOnIdentifier("PlayVC")
}
```

Your REST API query response is processed in a background thread when you call `URLSession.shared.dataTask` and so when you call any UI actions, you should wrap the code as above to execute the UI code in the main thread. Then it would work fine :)

Comment: Great :) Could you please mark the answer as "correct" if it helped?